# Creating a custom FormatStyle for all Measurement Units

Tags: swift, measurementformatter

I have a few measurements (like `UnitLength`, `UnitDuration`, `UnitSpeed` etc) and for most of them I want to have a formatter that uses the provided unit (`formatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit`).

To simplify the call site, I created a custom FormatStyle - for length it looks like this:

```
struct ProvidedUnitFormatStyle: FormatStyle {
    func format(_ measurement: Measurement<UnitLength>) -> String {
        let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
        formatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit
        return formatter.string(from: measurement)
    }
}

extension FormatStyle where Self == ProvidedUnitFormatStyle {
    static var providedUnit: ProvidedUnitFormatStyle { .init() }
}

// usage: distance.formatted(.providedUnit)
```

But if I want to do the same for `UnitDuration`, I'll have to repeat this code.

I tried using `Measurement<Dimension>` in `func format()`, hoping I'll be able to use this for all units, but the compiler complains:

> *Instance method 'formatted' requires the types `Measurement<Dimension>` and `Measurement<UnitDuration>` be equivalent*

Is there a way to achieve this without repeating the code for every `Unit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can pass a generic `Dimension` type and then use `MeasurementFormatter`.

```
struct ProvidedUnitFormatStyle<D: Dimension>: FormatStyle where D: Unit {
    func format(_ measurement: Measurement<D>) -> String {
        let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
        formatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit
        return formatter.string(from: measurement)
    }
}

extension FormatStyle {
    static func providedUnit<D: Dimension>(for dimension: D.Type) -> Self where Self == ProvidedUnitFormatStyle<D> {
        return ProvidedUnitFormatStyle<D>()
    }
}

// Usage:
let distance = Measurement(value: 100, unit: UnitLength.meters)
let duration = Measurement(value: 60, unit: UnitDuration.seconds)

let distanceString = distance.formatted(.providedUnit(for: UnitLength.self))
let durationString = duration.formatted(.providedUnit(for: UnitDuration.self))
```

```
print(distanceString) // 100 m
print(durationString) // 60 sec
```